Icons stay on screen after app crashes
Sometimes after an app crashes, the icon for it stays on the screen. It's in the foreground, blocking my view of any other apps. The attached screenshot shows the remnants of four crashes. This is happening in Ubuntu 24.04, but I've seen it before in older versions too. I'm interested in knowing

can this be prevented?
if not, how do I make them go away without restarting gnome?


